# How to extract EXIF data from jpeg files in Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to extract EXIF data from several jpeg files located in one of my Google Drive folders, using a Google Script.

More accurately, I would like to extract the date at which the photo was taken, together with associated keywords / description of the image, previously created with Adobe Lightroom.

I know that several scripts allowing to extract EXIF data from a file exist on internet, but I didn't manage to link them, or to use them with my own Google script.

How can I do that easily ? 
(I am a beginner on Google Script, please be as precise as possible)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 8):

The DriveApp service of Google Apps Script doesn't provide access to the details you're looking for, but the Advance Drive Service does.

#### Code.gs

You will need to enable the Advanced Drive service, [following instructions here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```js
// Demo use of getPhotoExif()
// Logs all files in a folder named "Photos".
function listPhotos() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Photos").next().getFiles();
  var fileInfo = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log("File: %s, Date taken: %s",
               file.getName(),
               getPhotoExif(file.getId()).date || 'unknown');
  }
}

/**
 * Retrieve imageMediaMetadata for given file. See Files resource
 * representation for details.
 * (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files)
 *
 * @param {String} fileId    File ID to look up
 *
 * @returns {object}         imageMediaMetadata object
 */
function getPhotoExif( fileId ) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
  var metaData = file.imageMediaMetadata;

  // If metaData is 'undefined', return an empty object
  return metaData ? metaData : {};
}
```

In the Google Drive API, the [resource representation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) for a File includes properties for the EXIF data:

```js
  "imageMediaMetadata": {
    "width": integer,
    "height": integer,
    "rotation": integer,
    "location": {
      "latitude": double,
      "longitude": double,
      "altitude": double
    },
    "date": string,
    "cameraMake": string,
    "cameraModel": string,
    "exposureTime": float,
    "aperture": float,
    "flashUsed": boolean,
    "focalLength": float,
    "isoSpeed": integer,
    "meteringMode": string,
    "sensor": string,
    "exposureMode": string,
    "colorSpace": string,
    "whiteBalance": string,
    "exposureBias": float,
    "maxApertureValue": float,
    "subjectDistance": integer,
    "lens": string
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. More precisely, how to get the date the photo was taken (because here, the date seems to be the date when the file was created), and also, how to get its Keywords Tags ? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Not sure why think `file.imageMediaMetadata.date` is the date a file was created - file creation isn't an image property. (It is in `file.createdDate`, just check the linked doc, and also available from DriveApp `File.getDateCreated()` - try it yourself, you'll find it's not the same as the date provided.) Keywords is one of many fields not currently supported.

Comment: 1) Indeed, the two dates are effectively different. But neither of them is the one I want : it seems that File.getDateCreated() provides the date the file has been created/uploaded in Drive, and file.imageMediaMetadata.date provides the date the file has been created on my computer (Lightroom export date). But I would like to extract the date the photo has been taken. This date appears well when I look the file in my computer in Windows Explorer, so this date is well somewhere in the file. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: 2) For keywords tags, knowing the structure of a jpeg file, is there any way to look for the right EXIF / IPTC marker corresponding to keywords tags ? I think that this is possible, but first I have to convert the file in UTF-8 and look for these specifics markers. The problem is that when I use the function file.getBlob().getDataAsString("UTF-8") and look at it in the console, some parts are decrypted, but other parts are filled with odd interogations marks.. There is something I don't understant but I don't know what.

Comment: You should gather those thoughts and ask another question. I think your original has been answered, so pursuing this in comments isn't providing benefit to the larger community.

Comment: [--> First Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627856/how-extract-the-date-a-photo-has-been-taken-using-google-script)

Comment: [--> Second Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630134/how-to-extract-keywords-tags-from-a-photo-using-google-script)