# How get EXIF from image by url in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, exif

I have a lot of images (a few thousand) on amazon cloud, and I have a url for each file (jpeg). I need to get exif inf from each photo and create a sheet with this data.

I tried save img to google drive and use this tutorial [How to extract EXIF data from jpeg files in Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582284/how-to-extract-exif-data-from-jpeg-files-in-drive)

```
function getPhotoExif(url) {

  var img =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) ,
      img_file = DriveApp.createFile(img.getBlob()),
      img_file_id = img_file.getId(),
      file = Drive.Files.get(img_file_id),
      metaData = file.imageMediaMetadata;

  Logger.log(metaData)
}
```

I expected that to work, but I have this error:

```
"ReferenceError: Drive is not defined (line 20, file "Code")"
```

Could you tell me how to get exif without saving the file to Google Drive or in any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it said on the tutorial that you provided, did you?

> You will need to enable the Advanced Drive service, following
>   instructions here.